# Energy gap in superconductors

Tags: superconductivity

According to [this set of lecture notes](http://theory.fi.infn.it/casalbuoni/barcellona.pdf), the first experimental evidence of an energy gap of order $T_{c}$ in superconductors was in 1955 when Corak et al. measured the specific heat of a superconductor and found that in the superconducting state the specific heat behaves as 
$$c_{s}=a \gamma T_{c} e^{-b T_{c}/T}$$ with $b \approx 1.5$ while in the normal state we have 
$$c_{n}=\gamma T \, .$$

I think I am missing something simple here, but I do not understand how this implies that there is a minimum excitation energy per particle $\approx 1.5 T_{c}$, can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score -1):

The specific heat is proportional to the density of electrons in the conduction band. And, in equilibrium, the electron density obeys the [Fermi-Dirac distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%E2%80%93Dirac_statistics) which, when a band gap exists, is well-approximated by the Boltzmann factor $\exp(-E_g/T)$.

Comment: -1 besides quoting the wrong physical equation,  you didn't explain the origin of the 1.5 factor.

Comment: @user157879 In what way is the equation wrong? Moreover, the OP did not ask us to explain the origin of the 1.5, rather to explain how the $1.5T_c$ corresponds to a minimum energy excitation - which I did in terms of the band gap.